# Issue in getImageWritersByFormatName for Tiff. Getting image writer

Tags: java, image, maven, tomcat, tiff

I am trying to convert PDF to tif images. I use following code to get the image writers by format.

```
Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF");

        if (writers == null || !writers.hasNext()) {
            throw new ImageWritingException();
        }
```

This works fine when I run the application standalone in Eclipse. But when I deploy the application to tomcat server in linux, **writers==null** is false but **!writers.hasNext** is true resulting to throw Exception.

I use maven to build the project to war.

I have following dependencies in the pom file.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.icepdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>icepdf-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai_imageio</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai_core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

What can be the difference between two environments? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If I recall, Tiff isn't supported out of the box, you need the JAI plugin for it...

Comment: I think the last dependency that I have indicated is jai_core. Also, as I said it is working fine in dev machine eclipse. Only when deployed to Tomcat server in linux, the problem arise

Comment: Have you placed the `jai_core` in the Java's `ext` directory?

Comment: in server java folder /java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/ext I don't have jai_core. Nor I have in my local machine too. I have added the maven dependency in the project. So the jar is in project target lib folder. Do I have to put the jar in server java ext folder?

Comment: As far as I can remember, yes.  We had issues when it wasn't located there and tried using custom class loaders to load our application.  Once we put it in there, it all worked

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. But there will be a problem if the jar in both places isn't it? I will try both. Thanks mate

Comment: The JVM should be deferring to the highest authority.  The Jars in the ext directory get loaded first, so when the class loaders go looking class, they check the parents first...from memory...so they should find the classes from the ext directory first

Comment: It did work. Thanks a lot. If you have time, please put the suggestion as the answer. I was debugging this thing from yesterday, even had "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error too as result of debugging and size of heap been not enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiff support is provided by the Java Advanced Imaging plugin `jai_core.jar`.

In order to work correctly, the jar file needs to be added to the JVM's `ext` directory, otherwise it won't register properly

Answer (score 5):

I met the same issue and found the root cause.

Let me summarize first, the issue does not occur in eclipse on dev machine, and it occurs on Tomcat server.

The root cause is that the imageio uses SPI, and there is a basic implementation in JDK (please refer to rt.jar, we can find it with two plugins for bmp and jpeg.) while the plugins we wants are in jai_imageio.jar.

With default configuration, Tomcat scans the one in rt.jar for plugins during initialization for ImageIO. Later when the application runs, the jai_imageio.jar won't be scanned.

As a result the plugins in jai_imageio.jar are not available. When running in dev machine, jai_imageio.jar is scanned.

There are several solutions as listed below, i would recommend the first one as it fits the design intention of ImageIO.

1. without changing the tomcat default configuration, re-scan the jar.

   static {
           ImageIO.scanForPlugins();
   }
2. changing the tomcat configuration, so tomcat won't initialize ImageIO.
   edit file /conf/server.xml，add appContextProtection="false" like following:

<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"  appContextProtection="false" />

With suchconfiguration, tomcat won't call ImageIO.getCacheDirectory in JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener, so ImageIO is not initialized until our codes runs.

Comment: Faced same problem. Tried the first point. Just placed the static block in the class that uses the conversion functionality... Great answer

Comment: It works!! Option 1 all day long ;-)  This should be marked as Accepted Answer

Answer (score 0):

Got my writer like this :

```
TIFFImageWriterSpi tiffSpi = new TIFFImageWriterSpi();
ImageWriter imageWriter = tiffSpi.createWriterInstance();
```